# Is it possible to target/jump to a specific iteration/loop and output it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Following my javascript code below:

```
function ready() {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
    var current = items[i];
    var name = current.getElementsByClassName('item-title')[0].innerText;
    var price = parseInt(current.getElementsByClassName('item-price')[0].innerText);
    var products = {};
    products.title = name;
    products.cost = price;
    data.push(products);
    console.log(data)
 }
```

I get the result below:

```
[{title: "Jack Daniels 1L", cost: 60}] (1)

[{title: "Jack Daniels 1L", cost: 60}, {title: "Southern Comfort 2L", cost: 130}] (2)

[{title: "Jack Daniels 1L", cost: 60}, {title: "Southern Comfort 2L", cost: 130}, {title: "Golden Label 1L", cost: 120}] (3)

[{title: "Jack Daniels 1L", cost: 60}, {title: "Southern Comfort 2L", cost: 130}, {title: "Golden Label 1L", cost: 120}, {title: "Grey Goose 1L", cost: 31}] (4)

[{title: "Jack Daniels 1L", cost: 60}, {title: "Southern Comfort 2L", cost: 130}, {title: "Golden Label 1L", cost: 120}, {title: "Grey Goose 1L", cost: 31}, {title: "Remy Martins 750ml", cost: 45}] (5)

[{title: "Jack Daniels 1L", cost: 60}, {title: "Southern Comfort 2L", cost: 130}, {title: "Golden Label 1L", cost: 120}, {title: "Grey Goose 1L", cost: 31}, {title: "Remy Martins 750ml", cost: 45}, {title: "Hennessy 1L", cost: 68}] (6)

[{title: "Jack Daniels 1L", cost: 60}, {title: "Southern Comfort 2L", cost: 130}, {title: "Golden Label 1L", cost: 120}, {title: "Grey Goose 1L", cost: 31}, {title: "Remy Martins 750ml", cost: 45}, {title: "Hennessy 1L", cost: 68}, {title: "Johnnie Walker 1L", cost: 50}] (7)

[{title: "Jack Daniels 1L", cost: 60}, {title: "Southern Comfort 2L", cost: 130}, {title: "Golden Label 1L", cost: 120}, {title: "Grey Goose 1L", cost: 31}, {title: "Remy Martins 750ml", cost: 45}, {title: "Hennessy 1L", cost: 68}, {title: "Johnnie Walker 1L", cost: 50}, {title: "Double Black 750ml", cost: 55}] (8)
```

With each iteration, one more object is added to the succeeding array, meaning it is only the last array that has everything as desired. Is it possible to target the specific array that results on the eighth loop and log it alone as the result? i.e this specific array:

```
[{title: "Jack Daniels 1L", cost: 60}, {title: "Southern Comfort 2L", cost: 130}, {title: "Golden Label 1L", cost: 120}, {title: "Grey Goose 1L", cost: 31}, {title: "Remy Martins 750ml", cost: 45}, {title: "Hennessy 1L", cost: 68}, {title: "Johnnie Walker 1L", cost: 50}, {title: "Double Black 750ml", cost: 55}] (8)
```

Comment: Please indent your code.  I don't understand the question "Is it possible to target the specific array"?  There is only one loop in your code and it starts with 0, you could start that at the 8th element with var i = 7 if that is what you are asking.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are you trying to log after N elements or after the entire loop has completed? If the latter, put the log statement outside the loop. If the former, do you know what N is every time? If yes, just check if (i == N). If no, how do you know the one you want?

Comment: Just move the `console.log()` outside of the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
function ready() {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
  var data = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
    var current = items[i];
    var name = current.getElementsByClassName('item-title')[0].innerText;
    var price = parseInt(current.getElementsByClassName('item-price')[0].innerText);
    var products = {};
    products.title = name;
    products.cost = price;
    data.push(products);

    //if you want to see what data looks like on the 8th iteration specifically, console.log with an if condition:
    if(i === 7) {
      console.log(data);
    };
  };

  //if you want to see what data looks like after the loop, console.log here:
  console.log(data);

  //...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would move the console.log() just below the for loop, you see that there is only one array that is filed with all pushed values. No need to change the array behaviour at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` statement to select an iteration which should be added:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (i === 7)
    {
        var current = items[i];
        var name = current.getElementsByClassName('item-title')[0].innerText;
        var price = parseInt(current.getElementsByClassName('item-price')[0].innerText);
        var products = {};
        products.title = name;
        products.cost = price;
        data.push(products);
        console.log(data)
    }
 }
```

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

> The if statement executes a statement if a specified condition is
> truthy. If the condition is falsy, another statement can be executed.

Comment: At that rate there's no point in using a for loop. Just do the operation a single time on items[7].

Comment: @David maybe it would be useful if OP wants to work with other indexes. In addition, this prevent to push `undefined` value, if array does not have such index